# How to change properties of a class in the ObjectDataSource Updating-Event when the update method accepts the business class as parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, objectdatasource, detailsview

I have the following situation:

My business class:

```
public class Foo
{
 public String A {get;set;}
 public DateTime B {get;set;}
 // .. and other properties like
 public String Intern {get;set;}
}
```

I'm binding that Item to a DetailsView in Editmode. (I bind a List containing a single object of Foo, becuase I do recall that I can only bind IEnumerable<> classes to the DetailView)
The binding is done via a ObjectDataSource

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsEditfoo" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetFooAsList" 
    TypeName="mynamespace.FooMethods" 
        DataObjectTypeName="mynamespace.Foo" 
        oninserting="odsEditfoo_Inserting" onupdating="odsEditfoo_Updating" 
        UpdateMethod="UpdateFoo">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="A" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="-1" />
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="-1" Name="type" Type="Object" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

The updatemethod looks like

```
public void UpdateFoo(Foo item) 
{
   // save changes ...
}
```

The changes that are done in the DetailsView are present in the item instance. Unfortunetly I can't display every property such as the property Intern. As the item is bound to the DetailView I have all the necessary information. All none displayed properties are lost in the item the moment the postback occurs.

I'm looking for a way I'm used to have from the LinqDataSource, where I have an Updating-Event that allows me access to the bound object, in this case an instance of foo, to alter properties. I can't seem to figure out how to this in the Updating-Event of the ObjectDataSource. What must I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
protected void odsEditfoo_Updating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
{
  Foo item = (Foo)(e.InputParameters["item"]);
}
```